# MVC Session SQLServer doesn't allow updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a fairly basic MVC4 website. I'm using SQL Server sessions like so:

```
<sessionState 
      mode="SQLServer" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="1440"
      sqlConnectionString="Password=pass; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=user; Data Source=server;" 
      />
```

When a user logs in, I add an item to the session like so:

```
Session["test"] = 3;
```

That works fine, the issue arises when I try to add new items to the session or update existing values, ie:

```
Session["test"] = 4;
Session["faux"] = 8;
```

As I'm debugging, the initial `"test"` value never gets updated, and the `"faux"` value is never added. No error is thrown, and if I step into/over the update/add code, the session looks like it's being updated, but if I step into another function and try to query the session, only the original values exist in the session.

I followed these instructions: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and the tables are showing up on my server.

I'm at a loss. Why would I be able to create a session, but never update/add values in that session?

Comment: Since I am unable to reproduce the issue in my local, and the answer below is not working, I would delete the answer. This is quite strange. There could be a problem in the ASPState DB setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in one controller I had `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]` (which was the controller that was working properly), and in the other controller (the one that was not working properly), I had `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` set, which is why my session items were never being updated. This was not an issue when my session state was InProc.

I'm keeping this question open in-case anyone else makes the same bad mistake that I did.